# Google example android-SynchronizedNotifications does not work

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

Google example android-SynchronizedNotifications does not work because it could not connect to Google API Client.
How to fix it?

I downloaded https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SynchronizedNotifications/ and ran application in emulator in Android Studio. 
This example uses Wearable.API in GoogleApiClient.Builder and it failed with error:

```
08-27 12:38:40.355 2532-2532/com.example.android.wearable.synchronizednotifications
E/SynchronizedFragment: Failed to connect to Google API Client
```

From debugging I got a reason:

> API_UNAVAILABLE: connectionResult = {ConnectionResult@4465}
>   "ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null,
>   message=null}"

Details of my setup:

OS - MAC X El Capitan

Java - jdk1.8.0_102

Project was compiled with API 23 (marshmallow) with installed Google APIs, Google Play services, Google repository, Android Support repository

Emulator - from Android Studio, API 23, Nexus 5

I did not use any credentials for Google APIs like OAuth 2.0 for Google Play Android Developer API or API keys because I could not find any information that for using Wearable.API in GoogleApiClient.Builder you need to use any kind of credentials.

Comment: Have to ask this: are you using an emulator image that includes the Google APIs? You don't mention it in your environment description.

Comment: Yes, emulator uses SDK that uses Google APIs.  As I wrote in my post: Project was compiled with API 23 (marshmallow) with installed Google APIs, Google Play services, Google repository, Android Support repository

Comment: For clarification: I ran Application module (that is for Mobile phone) of that example project.

Comment: I wasn't asking about the compile environment, I was asking about runtime. When you create an emulator instance, it doesn't necessarily include the Google APIs, and that could be the source of your problem.

Comment: I saw in some article that ConnectionResult.API_UNAVAILABLE error happens because emulator did not have Android Wear app is installed. I tried to install Android Wear app on emulator, but Google play said that no device is available.

Comment: I have in SDK Platforms tab for Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) installed:
Google APIs,
Android SDK Platform 23,
Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System image,
Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System image,
ARM EABI v7a System image,
Intel x86 Atom System image,
Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System image,
Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System image.

I used that image for emulator: 
Marshmallow, API level 23, ABI x86, Android 6.0 (with Google APIs)

Comment: It looks that the Google example can be run only on real mobile device, or not on emulator from Android studio. Does any other emulator support Android Wear app?